# Programmatic authorization in JAAS

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jaas, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

I have one requirement to add an authorization (authority) constraint programmatically (hereby not authentication). I have an application scoped CDI managed bean as follows.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {
    @Inject
    private Service service;
    private List<Entity>list;

    public Bean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize the list on application start up.
        // The service.getList() method in an EJB is authenticated anonymously
        // for the first time on application start up.
        list=service.getList();

        // Do something programmatically to enforce the authority ROLE_ADMIN afterwords.
    }

    // This method is only invoked by an admin (ROLE_ADMIN) as and when required.
    // The @PostConstruct method may however be invoked by an anonymous user on start up.
    public void action() {
        initialize();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to enforce an authority/role programmatically right before the method decorated with `@PostConstruct` finishes so that the `service.getList()` EJB method is only invoked by the user(s) having the said `ROLE_ADMIN` authority once the method decorated with `@PostConstruct` finishes its job?

In other words, it behaves exactly as shown below afterwords - once `@PostConstruct` finishes its job?

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"})
@RolesAllowed(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})
public class Skeleton implements Service {

    @Override
    public List<Entity> getList() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entity e").getResultList();
    }
}
```

I am currently using GlassFish Server 4.1 but it would be better, if the answer(s) were container-agnostic.

Comment: Maybe [this will help](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-javaee002.htm#GJGCS)

Comment: I don't think this makes much sense in the context of a `@ApplicationScoped` bean.

Comment: @peeskillet : That entire page merely describes usage of `@DeclareRoles`, `@RolesAllowed` and `@RunAs`. It does not say anything about assigning an authority/role dynamically at run time i.e. "*programmatically*".

Comment: @SteveC : I completely failed to get to you.

Comment: This bean is `@ApplicationScoped`. All users will access the same instance and it's `@PostConstruct` method will only ever be called once (per application node). You're asking that it be initialised depending upon the roles to which the very first user to access it is entitled.

Comment: @SteveC : The bean instance itself is not to be initialized. Those are only instance members (`private List<Entity>list;`) which are to be initialized. The `@PostConstruct` method calls another method `initialize()` which in turn calls an EJB method (`getList()`) where no roles need to be granted at that time, since the EJB specifies/declares no security constraints (authority). The constraints should be specified prgrammatically right before the `@PostConstruct` method finishes. The EJB method `getList()` in turn, is then guaranteed to be invoked only by an admin via the `action()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure will work, but you can try the following. Create an EJB Bean receiving SessionContext and then uses the method isCallerInRole(role).

```
@Stateless
public class AuthorizationBean {
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    public Boolean isCallerInRole(String role){
     return this.sessionContext.isCallerInRole(role);
    }
}
```

Inject this bean in your class and then check the role. The problem here is the scope of its class (ApplicationScoped), for this not sure whether it will work.

Comment: The nature of the question is completely different. It is not about a user's authority check or a permission check. The EJB where the method `getList()` resides is authenticated anonymously, when it is called for the first time because it is called on application start up (from within a `@PostConstruct` method which is invoked only once per application scope either lazily or eagerly). It will fail with a security exception, if the method itself or the EJB in question is assigned a role/authority declaratively (using `@RolesAllowed(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN"})`) and if it is attempted anonymously.

Comment: The point here is that the authority `ROLE_ADMIN` should be assigned right before the `@PostConstruct` method finishes so that the method or EJB can be granted the authority `ROLE_ADMIN` afterwards i.e the EJB method `getList()` should be invoked anonymously for the very first time the application scope bean is loaded but it should be granted the authority `ROLE_ADMIN` afterwards/then onwards on every call to that method except the first call from the `@PostConstruct` method. It is a very special case and not needed all the times.

Comment: By the way, this check `sessionContext.isCallerInRole(role);` can also be simulated on the web layer itself, if needed using `HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")`. There is no need to use `SessionContext` or `EjbContext` for this to be so on the web layer.

Comment: Ok @Tiny, really did not understand your question this way. In fact the role of the user can be seen both on the web layer as in ejb, but then thought it would be appropriate to make the EJB precisely because you could remove the RolesAllowed annotation and then see who is the user and their permission via SessionContext within the same method. If your requirement does not allow you to remove RollesAllowed then can try using reflection, aop or bytecode manipulation (javaassist) to try to add or remove the annotations at runtime, for example, add the PermitAll annotation and then remove it.

Comment: I do not know if this would work as an EJB is already fully handled by the server, but is an attempt.